# What does it mean by $t=-1$?

Tags: kinematics, vectors

if the position vector of a particle is $\hat{r}=\left(4+3t\right)\hat{\imath}+\left(t^3\right)\hat{\jmath}+\left(-5t\right)\hat{k}$, i want to find at what time this particle passes through the point $\left(1,\:-1,\:5\right)$. I found that $t=-1$ for this particle to pass through that point. What does it mean by that? Why there's negative sign for $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you defined the zero of time as when the particle is at $(4,0,0)$.  It passed through $(1,-1,5)$ one second before that.